# React Hooks: Is there a reason why leaving out the create or respectively the callback for useEffect and useCallback is bad?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I was reading ["A complete Guide to useEffect"](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov and the [Hooks docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies).

In the article Dan gives the following example:

```js
function SearchResults() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('react');

  // ✅ Preserves identity until query changes
  const getFetchUrl = useCallback(() => {
    return 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=' + query;
  }, [query]);  // ✅ Callback deps are OK

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = getFetchUrl();
    // ... Fetch data and do something ...
  }, [getFetchUrl]); // ✅ Effect deps are OK

  // ...
}
```

And the Hook docs give this:

```js
function ProductPage({ productId }) {
  // ✅ Wrap with useCallback to avoid change on every render
  const fetchProduct = useCallback(() => {
    // ... Does something with productId ...
  }, [productId]); // ✅ All useCallback dependencies are specified

  return <ProductDetails fetchProduct={fetchProduct} />;
}

function ProductDetails({ fetchProduct })
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProduct();
  }, [fetchProduct]); // ✅ All useEffect dependencies are specified
  // ...
}
```

I was wondering: are callback and factory function really necessary?

You could also write:

```js
const getFetchUrl = useCallback('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=' + query, [query]);
```

and

```js
useEffect(fetchProduct, [fetchProduct]);
```

Similarly you could think of a scenario where you could leave the create function out for `useMemo`:

```js
function Greeting({ name }) {
  const calculateExpensive = useCallback(() => {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
  }, [name]);

  const result = useMemo(calculateExpensive, [calculateExpensive]);
  return <p>{result}</p>;
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing a stupid mistake here. What am I not seeing and doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for using `useCallback` is to keep the same reference to a function between renders when needed.

`useCallback` is supposed to accept callback function as an argument, as the name suggests. Since `useCallback(fn)` is a shortcut for `useMemo(() => fn)`, it technically can be (mis)used with any argument:

```
const getFetchUrl = useCallback('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=' + query, [query]);
```

There are no benefits from doing this because `useMemo` and `useCallback` are intended for lazy evaluation, while this results in eager evaluation.

The example with `getFetchUrl` callback isn't very illustrative because memoization doesn't provide any improvements, it could be simplified to:

```
function SearchResults() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('react');

  const fetchUrl = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=' + query;

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... Fetch data and do something ...
  }, [fetchUrl]);
}
```

As for `Greeting` example, `useCallback` is redundant. If the calculation is really expensive and needs to be lazily evaluated (in this example it isn't), this is what `useMemo` is for:

```
function Greeting({ name }) {
  const result = useMemo(() => {
    return `Hello ${name}`;
  }, [name]);

  return <p>{result}</p>;
}
```

Comment: I know that those examples don't hold up in the real world 
The question is: is there a reason you shouldn't leave out the callback and create functions for `useCallback`, `useEffect` and `useMemo`? Maybe internally? Or is the only consequence that you evaluate eagerly instead of lazily?

Comment: There's a bunch of use cases for useCallback. The most common is when you pass a callback as a prop to child component and you don't want it to be newed on each render because this will cause a re-render in a child even if it's pure (ProductDetails example, notice that useCallback and useEffect are in different comps). The primary use case for useMemo is to skip function calls for expensive function. A combo of useCallback/useMemo and useEffect in the same component  (SearchResults example) is IMO exotic and redundant. You can likely do this with useEffect alone.